# Avro Producer sending key without key schema

Tags: python, apache-kafka, avro, kafka-producer-api

I am using Avro Producer in Python 2.7. I need to send a message with a key and value,
the value has Avro-Schema in the topic, but there is not Avro-Schema for the key (I can't add Schema for the key - legacy reasons).

This is my Code:

```
def main():
    kafkaBrokers = os.environ.get('KAFKA_BROKERS')
    schemaRegistry = os.environ.get('SCHEMA_REGISTRY')
    topic = os.environ.get('KAFKA_TOPIC')

    subject = '${}-value'.format(topic)
    sr = CachedSchemaRegistryClient(schemaRegistry)

    schema = sr.get_latest_schema(subject).schema

    value_schema = avro.loads(str(schema))

    url = 'test.com'

    value = {'url': u'test.com', 'priority': 10}

    avroProducer = AvroProducer({
        'bootstrap.servers': kafkaBrokers,
        'schema.registry.url': schemaRegistry
    }, default_value_schema=value_schema)


    key = 1638895406382020875
    
    avroProducer.produce(topic=topic, value=value, key=key)
    avroProducer.flush()
```

I get the following error:

```
raise KeySerializerError("Avro schema required for key")
confluent_kafka.avro.serializer.KeySerializerError: Avro schema required for key
```

If I delete the key from the produce function:

```
avroProducer.produce(topic=topic, value=value)
```

It works.

How is it possible to send the key without having schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use regular Producer and execute the serialization functions yourself

```
from confluent_kafka import avro
from confluent_kafka.avro import CachedSchemaRegistryClient
from confluent_kafka.avro.serializer.message_serializer import MessageSerializer as AvroSerializer

avro_serializer = AvroSerializer(schema_registry)
serialize_avro = avro_serializer.encode_record_with_schema  # extract function definition 

value_schema = avro.load('avro_schemas/value.avsc')  # TODO: Create avro_schemas folder 

p = Producer({'bootstrap.servers': bootstrap_servers})

value_payload = serialize_avro(topic, value_schema, value, is_key=False)
p.produce(topic, key=key, value=value_payload, callback=delivery_report)
```

Comment: MessageSerializer will be sufficient enough for serialize the object as avro serialization?

Comment: Yes. I simply renamed it `import MessageSerializer as AvroSerializer`

Answer (score 1):

`AvroProducer` assumes that both keys and values are encoded with the schema registry, prepending a magic byte and the schema id to the payload of both the key and the value.

If you want to use a custom serialization for the key, you could use a `Producer` instead of an `AvroProducer`. But it will be your responsibility to serialize the key (using whatever format you want) and the values (which means encoding the value and prepending the magic byte and the schema id). To find out how this is done you can look at the `AvroProducer` code.

But it also means you'll have to write your own `AvroConsumer` and won't be able to use the `kafka-avro-console-consumer`.

Comment: deserializer parameters can be passed to the avro console consumer for non-Avro keys